# Progentius vs Cowardice

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So my friend thinks that [Cowardice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Cowardice) will get rid of [Progenitus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Progenitus) but since a spell can't target [Progenitus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Progenitus) it can't target it. Now he also said I can target it but it fizzles but he would be doing an illegal move if I'm correct.

What can get [Progenitus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Progenitus) off the field? I know counterspells can and anything that doesn't directly target [Progenitus](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Progenitus) such as sacrifice a creature you control or [In Garruk's Wake](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383275) if I'm correct.

Basically as long as it doesn't specifically say target creature?

I'm doing a hydra deck but my friends run counterspells so I'm thinking of using Boseiju, Who Shelters All, Cavern of Souls, Grand Abolisher, and Banefire. (White Green Hydras) (Can run red for Bane)

Basically I wanna be able to get my big creatures on the field without being countered (also this would be on side board since only 2 of my friends run counters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct that Cowardice is of no benefit vs. Progenitus.  Declaring Progenitus to be the target of something is an illegal action so you back up to just before it was done, it doesn't "Happen but fizzle."

The easy way to keep track of protection is the acronym DEBT.

D - Damage, the thing you have protection from cannot damage you

E - Enchant and Equip, the thing you have protection from cannot enchant you or be equipped to you

B - Block, the thing you have protection from cannot block you

T - Target, the thing you have protection from cannot target you

So, for example, [Day of Judgment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Day%20of%20Judgment) can remove Progenitus because it does none of those things.  [Fleshbag Marauder](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fleshbag%20Marauder) could also get rid of Progenitus if you have nothing else to sacrifice, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Cowardice will have no effect of old proggy. Cowardice bounces things that get targeted but because old proggy has protection from everything everything that is a thing cannot target it.

Remember the DEBT rule for when you are dealing with protection. A permanent with proteection from X cannot be...

Dealt DAMAGE from X

Enchanted / Equipped / Fortified  by X

Blocked by X

TARGETED by x

Comment: Even if a token had a targetted effect (e.g. you have a token copy of a creature with such an ability) it doesn't matter. Tokens are still a thing that exists in the game, therefore Progenitus has protection from _them_ too. By my interpretation Everything even extends to include Emblems, which are neither permanents, cards nor spells.

Comment: *2/1/2009 "Protection from everything" means the following: Progenitus can't be blocked, Progenitus can't be enchanted or equipped, Progenitus can't be the target of spells or abilities, and all damage that would be dealt to Progenitus is prevented.* This includes emblems that deal damage or target, but not emblems with static effects like +1/+1 to all creatures, which *would* affect Progenitus.